# Discord.py, how would I make the bot create a channel if it doesn't exists but if it does exists it will just carry on with it's task?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7, discord.py

I'm trying to make it so when someone gets warned (-warn @user reason) it'll say what user got warned, who they got warned by & why they got warned
Then, if the channel isn't already there, I want it to create a channel called "warn-logs" (#warn-logs when typing in Discord itself) but if the channel already exists with that name it'll keep going on with it's task & say: what user got warned, who they got warned by & why they got warned, I don't want it to log anything, just let the people know about the warn and save it to a channel

I've already tried everything I can find but nothing helped, not even the Python Discord server or Discord.py Discord server

This is the warn command itself & what I've done so far

```
@client.command()
@has_permissions(kick_members=True)
async def warn(ctx, member:discord.Member, *, arg):
 author = ctx.author
 guild = ctx.message.guild
 channel = await guild.create_text_channel('warn-logs')

 channel
 await ctx.send(f'{member.mention} warned for: {arg} warned by: {author.mention}')
 await member.send(f'{author.mention} warned you for: {arg}')
 await ctx.message.delete()
```

I get no error messages, all that happens is it creates a channel called warn-logs (even if one with the same name already exists) but doesn't send ANY messages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the current code should be sending messages in the channel the command is called from.  Is that happening?

You can use [`discord.utils.get`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.utils.get) to search for a channel with a particular name:

```
@client.command()
@has_permissions(kick_members=True)
async def warn(ctx, member:discord.Member, *, arg):
    author = ctx.author
    guild = ctx.guild
    channel = get(guild.text_channels, name='warn-logs')
    if channel is None:
        channel = await guild.create_text_channel('warn-logs')
    await channel.send(f'{member.mention} warned for: {arg} warned by: {author.mention}')
    await member.send(f'{author.mention} warned you for: {arg}')
    await ctx.message.delete()
```

Comment: yes it's sending it to the person warned & the channel the command was executed in, but I want it to create warn-logs (if the channel isn't already created, if it is then it'll carry on with the rest of the task) & send the message to warn-logs too

Comment: @DrJakaboii That is what happens

Comment: so i cant just make it create a logs channel if one doesnt exists and post the reson there?

Comment: @DrJakaboii That should be what the above code does.  Is it not doing that when you try it?  The `get` call should return the existing warn-logs channel.  If it returns `None` instead, the channel doesn't exist and we create it.